# How to install docker man pages on Mac os

Tags: macos, docker, manpage

I've installed docker on mac os as [written in documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/).

But in some docs (for example in the [docker book](http://www.dockerbook.com/)) I see the recomendations to use `man docker-run` (`man docker-pull`, etc).

But when I run such command I get the error:

```
bessarabov@bessarabov-osx:~$ man docker
No manual entry for docker
```

How can I install docker man-documentation to my Mac OS system?

Comment: They are available in your VM, and from the source: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/man/docker-run.1.md

Comment: Thank you, I've cloned this repo so I have docs for offline use, but I still want to be able to use `man docker-run` on my mac os host.

Comment: The manpages are not part of the boot2docker installation. You could file an issue here: https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/issues

Comment: @Krumelur Thank you! Here is the direct link to the issue with man pages https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/issues/66

Answer (score 8):

As of 2017.06.01, you have to git checkout your desired tag/version from

- version `>=` 17.06: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce
- version `<` 17.06: https://github.com/moby/moby

and then, go to the `components/cli` directory and execute:

```
make -f docker.Makefile manpages
```

To add the manpages to the manpath:

```
echo "MANPATH $PWD/man" | sudo tee -a /private/etc/man.conf
```

Source: https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/217

Comment: Thanks! And I upvoted the current (as of Apr 2022) [github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/743#issuecomment-928969594) in the current (lol again) repo!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like docker has slightly changed since @Sergiy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29284046/3903368). Here is a slightly updated version that worked for me.

```
git clone https://github.com/docker/docker.git
cd docker/man                      # looks like the directory has moved up
docker build -t docker/md2man .    # don't forget the '.'
docker run -v $PWD/:/docs:rw -w /docs -i docker/md2man /docs/md2man-all.sh
sudo cp -R man* /usr/share/man/    # you'll likely need sudo access for this
man docker                         # check it worked
```

Comment: This builds the master branch. If you want something that will build precisely the version of Docker you're using, check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/jasonmp85/9ab30cf7dfd1fb64cbe59cf55c2a7c4d

Answer (score 3):

Until the [issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/issues/66) is resolved you can [build man pages manually](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/man/README.md) via a docker container using the supplied Dockerfile and then just copy generated files to `/usr/share/man/`:

```
# Step 1: checkout docker sources, but make sure you do this
# somewhere in /Users directory because boot2docker can only
# share this path with docker containers
git clone https://github.com/docker/docker.git

# Step 2: build docker image  
cd docker/docs/man
docker build -t docker/md2man .

# Step 3: build man pages
docker run -v /Users/<path-to-git-dir>/docker/docs/man:/docs:rw \
-w /docs -i docker/md2man /docs/md2man-all.sh

# Step 4: copy generated man pages to /usr/share/man
cp -R man* /usr/share/man/
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Except that as of 2016/11/17 step 2 runs into **"Update failed for golang.org/x/sys: Cannot detect VCS"** errors. Trying to trac those down leads to discussions on go and glide github repos about the right way to do imports in those two utilities; but no current solutions via these docker/md2man based answers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the go/glide bits under the hood of docker/md2man have changed since @gilly's answer. What I ended up doing, on Mac OS:

```
cd /usr/local
git clone https://github.com/docker/docker.git
brew install ruby
gem install md2man
cd docker/man
mkdir man1; for i in *.1.md; md2man-roff $i > man1/${i%.md}; done
cd /usr/local/share/man/man1
for i in ../../../docker/man/man1/*.1; do ln -s $i .; done
```